# SQL Server Update trigger not working correctly

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have written an UPDATE trigger to look for changes in my `Test.dbo.receiving_podio_dump` table and then perform one of two different scenarios:

1. IF there is an existing `receiving_id` and existing `sku_no` match and this is an update to that combination in the `Test.dbo.receiving_detail` table, the appropriate row gets updated, OR
2. IF there is an existing `receiving_id` and but a new `sku_no` item, a new row needs to be added/inserted into the `Test.dbo.receiving_detail` table.

Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_receiving_detail_sku1_update
ON [Test].[dbo].[receiving_podio_dump]
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    --UPDATES DATA IN THE ROW FOR THAT RECEIVING LOG/SKU NO COMBO IF IT ALREADY EXISTS--
    IF (SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) 
        FROM inserted 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.receiving_detail AS rec ON (inserted.receiving_id = rec.receiving_id AND '001' = rec.sku_no)) <> 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[receiving_detail]
        SET receiving_assigned_id = inserted.receiving_assigned_id, 
            sku_id = sku1_id, sku = sku1, sku_lot = sku1_lot, 
            sku_whloc = sku1_whloc, sku_weight_of_unit = sku1_weight_of_unit, 
            sku_unit_of_weight_type = sku1_unit_of_weight_type, 
            sku_quantity_of_units = sku1_quantity_of_units, 
            sku_unit_of_measure = sku1_unit_of_measure, 
            sku_temperature = sku1_temperature
        FROM inserted
        WHERE ([dbo].[receiving_detail].receiving_id = inserted.receiving_id 
          AND [dbo].[receiving_detail].sku_no = '001')
    END

    --INSERTS A ROW FOR A NEW SKU NO FOR AN EXISTING RECEIVING LOG NUMBER--
    IF (SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) 
        FROM inserted 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.receiving_detail AS rec ON (inserted.receiving_id = rec.receiving_id AND '001' = rec.sku_no)) = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[receiving_detail] (receiving_id, receiving_assigned_id, sku_id, sku_no, sku, sku_lot, sku_whloc, sku_weight_of_unit, sku_unit_of_weight_type, sku_quantity_of_units, sku_unit_of_measure, sku_temperature)
            SELECT 
                inserted.receiving_id, inserted.receiving_assigned_id, sku1_id, 
                '001', sku1, sku1_lot, sku1_whloc, sku1_weight_of_unit, 
                sku1_unit_of_weight_type, sku1_quantity_of_units, 
                sku1_unit_of_measure, sku1_temperature
            FROM 
                inserted
            WHERE 
                sku1 IS NOT NULL
    END
END
GO
```

The first part of the trigger is working, and quantities of products are being updated on the `Test.dbo.receiving_detail` table if there is an update in the `Test.dbo.receiving_podio_dump` table.

However, if a totally new SKU is being added, a new row is not being inserted into my `Test.dbo.receiving_detail` table.

I am at a loss as to what to change, I have tried several things, any advice is welcome and appreciated. Thanks!

PS: the receiving log has a total of 24 SKU Items that can potentially be added or updated. I have only included the first trigger, but all of them follow this pattern.

Comment: Your first IF Condition is missing something

Comment: Thanks @CoridRocket actually my <> was there but invisible, I had to change this to &lt; and &gt; so that it would display correctly within the code block.

Comment: Some remarks: `COUNT(*)` can't ever be NULL, and checking if something exists in a resultset should be done using an `EXISTS` clause; that's much more efficient.

Comment: Also, both conditions can't be true, so make it `IF cond1 stmt1 ELSE stmt2`. The way you write it, `IF cond1 stmt1; IF NOT(cond1) stmt2;`, executing `stmt1` can cause `stmt2` to execute if executing `stmt1` makes `NOT(cond1)` evaluate as true.

Answer (score 0):

I remove both IF statements and added those Conditions on the UPDATE and INSERT statements to support the scenario of a mass update with both conditions are true.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_receiving_detail_sku1_update
ON [Test].[dbo].[receiving_podio_dump]
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    --UPDATES DATA IN THE ROW FOR THAT RECEIVING LOG/SKU NO COMBO IF IT ALREADY EXISTS--
    UPDATE rec
    SET receiving_assigned_id = i.receiving_assigned_id, 
            sku_id = sku1_id, sku = sku1, sku_lot = sku1_lot, 
            sku_whloc = sku1_whloc, sku_weight_of_unit = sku1_weight_of_unit, 
            sku_unit_of_weight_type = sku1_unit_of_weight_type, 
            sku_quantity_of_units = sku1_quantity_of_units, 
            sku_unit_of_measure = sku1_unit_of_measure, 
            sku_temperature = sku1_temperature
    FROM inserted i
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[receiving_detail] rec ON rec.receiving_id = i.receiving_id
    WHERE (rec.sku_no = '001')

    --INSERTS A ROW FOR A NEW SKU NO FOR AN EXISTING RECEIVING LOG NUMBER--
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[receiving_detail] (receiving_id, receiving_assigned_id, sku_id, sku_no, sku, sku_lot, sku_whloc, sku_weight_of_unit, sku_unit_of_weight_type, sku_quantity_of_units, sku_unit_of_measure, sku_temperature)
    SELECT 
        i.receiving_id, i.receiving_assigned_id, sku1_id, 
        '001', sku1, sku1_lot, sku1_whloc, sku1_weight_of_unit, 
        sku1_unit_of_weight_type, sku1_quantity_of_units, 
        sku1_unit_of_measure, sku1_temperature
    FROM 
        inserted i
    WHERE sku1 IS NOT NULL
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[receiving_detail] rec WHERE rec.receiving_id = i.receiving_id AND rec.sku_no = '001')
END


GO
```

Comment: Your solution worked!  You're a lifesaver!  You've got some mad SQL skills... Respect!  :)